# Javascript why do i get an error of 'addEventListener' undefined when everything works?

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to make an image slider for a client

I get this error in the console -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Even tho everything works perfectly fine? what is going on with the console? i cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Point 1. Please include any code that is relevant to your question in your question. Links to external sites are useless. Point 2: To demonstrate your issue with an image slider, use appropriate images or blank placeholders.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a SFW version, such as an MCVE using placeholder images? Some people are behind filters that flag contents/images that might be deemed inappropriate: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281251/how-should-we-handle-links-to-adult-content-in-posts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your link has unappropriate contents, but, by the way, your code (`main.js`) is:

```js
//IMAGE SCROLL
var slideLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('slideLeft');
var slideRight = document.getElementsByClassName('slideRight');
var imagesWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('imagesWrapper');

var nrOfImageWrappers = imagesWrapper.length;

for(let i = 0; i <= nrOfImageWrappers; i++){
  slideLeft[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    imagesWrapper[i].scrollLeft += -150;
  });

  slideRight[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    imagesWrapper[i].scrollLeft += 150;
  });
}
```

1. `let i = 0; i <= nrOfImageWrappers; i++`, at the last turn, causes the index to be out-of-range because the `length` property counts the number of items but their index starts form `0`, so, you need `i < nrOfImageWrappers`.

Comment: Im sorry it is not my content, its the one i work for who provided the images.. and it is not anything nude :) but thanks alot this was what i was looking for, do you know why i have to use "let" before it works ?